# Can't mysql_secure_installation a fresh MariaDB on fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to run mysql_secure_installation on a fresh install of MariaDB on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server. I installed via the exact instructions found [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/). When prompted for `Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]`, I provide a `[return]` to accept the default `Y`. I am then getting the following error:

`Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation: 203: /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation: cannot create .mysql.26327: Directory nonexistent
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation: 205: /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation: cannot open .mysql.26327: No such file
 ... Failed!
Cleaning up...`

Any ideas how to solve this? I always used this same process on 14.04 with success, so my hunch is it is some sort of bug or new way of doing things on Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you ran `mysql_secure_installation` you changed to a directory that no longer exists. To resolve the problem, change to a directory that exists, and run it again.

Comment: Oh, if that's really what I did, I'll feel stupid. Won't have a chance to test again until tomorrow, will let you know the results. Thanks.

Comment: Don't be. That script is stupid for trying to write temporary files in the current directory.